# How to use longpolling in Spring REST app with heroku?

Tags: java, spring, rest, http, heroku

I am trying to use DeferredResult for long-polling in a REST spring controller deployed to Heroku. However, Heroku h12 sends a timeout automatically after 30seconds if there is no data sent. I know Nodejs has [delayed response](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-delayed-response) which sends a single byte to keep the connection and avoid timeout. Is there any way to do this for Spring?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an example using Spring, but here is an example using raw Servlet (with AsyncContext from Servlet 3.0):

https://github.com/kissaten/slow-service-example/blob/master/src/main/java/Main.java

The important thing is to set the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header, and then periodically print whitespace to the response, which I did like this:

```
final ScheduledFuture chunkBlower = scheduledExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    try {
      async.getResponse().getWriter().print(" ");
      async.getResponse().getWriter().flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      // do nothing
    }
  }
}, 15, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```